# Login system with API integration

Tags: angular

I have a login system that works without an API. The username is "test" and the password is "1234".

I would like to create a system that handles 2 users. I created a `file.json` file with two users.

**file.json**

```
{
    "login": [{
            "id": 1,
            "user": "toto",
            "password": "1234"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user": "titi",
            "password": "1234"
        }
    ]

}
```

What files do I need to manage the connection with an API? Because I'm a beginner, I don't fully understand.

Which files should I modify/use in my project below, please?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ey2nzj?file=src/app/views/identity/identity.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want a system that will handle multiple authenticated users? If so, Just create a service that will handle your API calls under `/src/app/services` folder and store your users details like token in **localStorage**

Probably you can store a simple structure like this

```
{
 auth:[
  {token:'1231212', name:'user 1'},
  {token:'1231212', name:'user 2'}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created something similar with this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

You can use the normal http methods like get, post, etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).